# Workflow Order for making a Character

Tags: texturing, workflow, normals, baking, retopology

So I am working on a model for an animation I'm doing for my college. I have finished the sculpting and modelling stage but I am stuck on what order to take it from here. I have to retopo it and bake the normals but I also have to texture and rig it. I was wondering whether or not I am supposed to texture the high poly then bake the normals or bake the normals and then texture over the low poly that has the normal map. I am planning on baking in blender and then texturing in substance painter. I am just lost on what is the most efficient workflow order. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A lot depends on how your character looks like (is it stylized or realistic, how simple its form, etc) But generally after you finished sculpting you do retopology and UVs. Then, when you have both high poly and low poly versions done you can bake a normal map, AO, and displacement (if needed) from your high poly mesh to the low poly version. Then you start texturing your low-poly, not only creating other maps but probably you'll have to tweak your baked maps a bit. (so yep, do not texture high poly).
Anyway, you have to understand there is no one-and-only pipeline for making characters. Sometimes you may skip a stage or two if the shape or textures are simple. Or get back to some stages twice to get the result as clean as possible. It depends on the task, character design, and time limitations.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I appreciate it. I will retopo first, bake, then texture. It is a pretty detailed character so UV unwrapping the low poly will be ideal. I appreciate your help :)